# How to reload different objects by applicationsettingsbase?

Tags: c#

```
// TestASettingsString and TestBSettingsString are byte[]
// TestASettings and TestBSettings are two objects to be saved
```

In SettingsSaving, TestASettings and TestBSettings are serialized into two seperate byte arrays, and then saved (in some other function)

My question is how to recover TestASettings and TestBSettings from TestASettingsString  and TestASettingsString seperately in loadsavedsettings?

That is when I do 
formatter.Deserialize(stream);

How to seperate two totally different objects TestASettings and TestBSettings from formatter.Deserialize(stream)?

Thanks

```
private void SettingsSaving(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, TestASettings);
    // TestASettingsString and TestBSettingsString are byte[]
            TestASettingsString = stream.ToArray();

            stream.Flush();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, TestBSettings);
            TestBSettingsString = stream.ToArray();   

            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }





private void LoadSavedSettings()
    {
        Reload();
        // how to get TestASettings and TestBSettings from TestASettingsString  and
        // TestASettingsString seperately?
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect part of the problem is here:

```
        TestASettingsString = stream.ToArray();
        stream.Flush();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, TestBSettings);
        TestBSettingsString = stream.ToArray();
```

For `MemoryStream`, `Flush()` is a no-op. Do you actually mean:

```
        TestASettingsString = stream.ToArray();
        stream.SetLength(0);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, TestBSettings);
        TestBSettingsString = stream.ToArray();
```

which will reset the stream, giving `TestBSettingsString` as a *separate* chunk of data? Currently `TestBSettingsString` actually contains both `TestASettings` and `TestBSettings`.

With that done, it should just be a case of reversing things:

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(TestASettingsString)) {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    TestASettings = (WhateverType)bf.Deserialize(ms);
}
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(TestBSettingsString)) {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    TestBSettings = (WhateverOtherType)bf.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Note also: I suggest **not** using `BinaryFormatter` for persisting any thing offline (disk, database, etc).

Comment: @younevertell - did you add the `SetLength(0)` ?

Comment: but stream.SetLength(0); doesn't work. I closed the stream and get a new one

Answer (score 1):

Deserializing them requires code like this:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(TestASettingsString);
var fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
TestASettings = (TestAClass)fmt.Deserialize(ms);
```

Where TestAClass is the type of TestASettings.  You'll need to reset the stream in your serialization code, set the Position back to 0.